# getting correct path of a folder in python

Tags: python, path

I have a directory structure as below

```
/home/damon/dev/python/misc/path/
                                /project/mycode.py
                                /app/templates/
```

I need to get the absolute path of the templates folder from mycode.py

I tried to write `mycode.py` as

```
import os

if __name__=='__main__':
    PRJ_FLDR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print 'PRJ_FLDR=',PRJ_FLDR
    apptemplates = os.path.join(PRJ_FLDR,'../app/templates')
    print 'apptemplates=',apptemplates
```

I expected the apptemplates to be

```
/home/damon/dev/python/misc/path/app/templates
```

but I am getting

```
/home/damon/dev/python/misc/path/project/../app/templates
```

How do I get the correct path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import os

if __name__=='__main__':
    PRJ_FLDR=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print 'PRJ_FLDR=',PRJ_FLDR
    apptemplates = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PRJ_FLDR, '../app/templates'))
    print 'apptemplates=',apptemplates
```

Considering the comments, I made the proper edit.

Comment: this would yield `home/damon/dev/python/misc/path/project/app/templates` which is wrong..it should be `home/damon/dev/python/misc/path/app/templates`

Comment: I'd recommend joining the paths and then normalizing: `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PRJ_FLDR, '../app/templates'))`

Comment: Hugh is right, you need to do the join first then the abspath, otherwise the code is wrong. (Although it happens it will be correct when the working directory is PRJ_FLDR).

Answer (score 5):

That path *is* correct, try it. But if you want to remove the redundant 'project/../' section for clarity, use `os.path.normpath`

> `os.path.normpath(path)`
>
> Normalize a pathname. This collapses redundant separators and up-level references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath

Answer (score 0):

I tried this ,and it seems to work

```
parentpath=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))
apptemplates=os.path.join(parentpath,'app/templates')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
apptemplates = os.path.join(os.path.split(PRJ_FLDR)[0], "app/templates")
```